JavaFX scene refuses to load, even though it worked before
I was creating a JavaFX application when something I tried froze the program and I had to close it manually. However, instead of killing the program in IntelliJ, I instead clicked the X to close it. After this point, the window refused to open, getting stuck at stage.setScene().
I've cleared my build caches, I've regenerated the run task, I've restarted my computer, I've switched computers, and in those attempts it only loaded once or twice and then never again. I've tried switching from FXML to plain Java, setting the scene to a childless node (which seems to load) and then setting the node to a fully furnished Java one (which then it gets stuck).
Here is my code for what I have.
package gg.hipposgrumm.jsr_launcher;

import gg.hipposgrumm.jsr_launcher.scenes.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JSRLauncherMain extends Application {
    public static Stage popup;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        stage.setTitle("JSR Launcher");
        // Everything before this point executes.
        stage.setScene(new Scene(Home.create()));
        // Nothing after this point executes.
        stage.setMinWidth(240);
        stage.setMinHeight(120);
        stage.show();

        // More Code
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

package gg.hipposgrumm.jsr_launcher.scenes;

import gg.hipposgrumm.jsr_launcher.JSRLauncherMain;
import gg.hipposgrumm.jsr_launcher.util.Game;
import gg.hipposgrumm.jsr_launcher.util.saving.ServerInfo;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Home {
    public final BorderPane window;
    private final ComboBox<LoginInfo> accounts;
    private final ComboBox<ServerInfo> servers;

    private Home() {
        accounts = new ComboBox<>();
        accounts.setPromptText("Not Logged In");
        servers = new ComboBox<>();
        servers.setPromptText("No Server Selected");

        Button accountButton = new Button("Manage Accounts");
        accountButton.setOnAction((event) -> {
            try {
                JSRLauncherMain.popupLogin(false);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to open the Login menu please report with the following stacktrace: ", e);
            }
        });
        Button serverButton = new Button("Manage Servers");
        serverButton.setOnAction((event) -> {
            try {
                // TODO: Make this open the server menu.
                JSRLauncherMain.popupLogin(false);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to open the Server menu please report with the following stacktrace: ", e);
            }
        });
        BorderPane footer = new BorderPane(
                null,
                null,
                new HBox(servers, serverButton),
                null,
                new HBox(accounts,accountButton));
        footer.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        window = new BorderPane(new TabPane(
                // Tabs added here.
        ), null, null, footer, null);
        window.setMinSize(240, 120);
        window.setMaxSize(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        window.setPrefSize(800, 400);

        window.setUserData(this);
    }


    public static Parent create() {
        Home home = new Home();
        home.update();
        return home.window;
    }

    public void update() {
        // This does a thing.
    }
}


I wish I could include a repo but I currently want to keep the project private until release.

Why the double-brace initialization? (See this.)

Fine @BasilBourque, I removed all of the double braces in my project. Didn't fix anything though.

There is an unknown error in the code you don’t provide.  You can’t be helped with that.   A [mcve] may help.

@jewelsea I currently cannot provide a repo. I think I have sent a minimal reproducible example, and there are no errors printed to the console. All I know is that it gets stuck. I'm thinking that switching to python might not be such a bad idea.

If you're expecting that someone will look at the code you posted and tell you what the problem is and how to fix it, then I very much doubt that will happen. You are essentially asking for help in debugging your code. Pardon me, but it's not clear from your question whether you have already tried to debug your code. As far as I am aware, clearing build caches and restarting your computer do not constitute debugging your code. In order for me to help you debug your code, I first need to reproduce your problem. I believe most other people will also need to do the same in order to help you.

You may try removing final from your code. I am not quite sure what JFX does in your case. But Abra is right: Please provide a working minimal example. And: Switching a programming language because a bug encountering is not a good idea. This will happen again, only with another language. Find and fix the bug instead.

at least , you should post some  runtime error stack log for some troubleshooting

Which operating system does this issue appear on? CPU architecture? JavaFX version? Does the exact code (i.e., it can simply be copied, pasted, and executed as is) in your question reproduce the issue?

I’m not sure what the “minimal reproducible example” would be. I’ve pretty much stripped out anything that would likely be considered irrelevant and limited it to 2 classes (rather than the probably 20 that I have, many of which have no relationship to the issue).

The provided code does not compile - it cannot reproduce your issue. From the link: "Minimal: Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem, Complete: Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself, Reproducible: Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem".  Obviously, as the code does not compile, it does none of those things.

I'm just going to ask people on Discord (since it's much easier back and forth). Also how do I close this ticket?

The question is already closed.  If you want to delete it, see how to delete a question: "There's a gray delete-link directly below the post, above any comments."  As the question has already been closed it would probably be deleted automatically, though perhaps not with an accepted answer (I don't know the policy on that).  Also, I don't know if the delete link will still be there for you if the question is already closed.

"You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it."

As other said without a minimum reproductible example, it is not possible to give you a precise answer.
However, "it works once and not after" is typical of an application using a system resource (file, port...) and not releasing it properly.
In JavaFX, it's usually because the cross button doesn't send the interupt signal and stop the JVM. It just close the main Stage and stop the JavaFX framework. If other thread are created, then the JVM is kept alive by them and resources are not released (you should still have the process open in background).
Identify which resources could be lock and clean them properly after usage or when the stage close by doing :
public class JSRLauncherMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        stage.setTitle("JSR Launcher");
        
             
        // More Code
    }
    
    @Override
    public void stop() {
      // clear ressources
    }

Edit to use Applciation.stop() as comment suggest.

Resources on app shutdown can be released in a stop() method implementation: "This method is called when the application should stop, and provides a convenient place to prepare for application exit and destroy resources.".

I’ll try doing that.

This doesn't help me and I can't delete the question, so I guess I'll just mark this as correct.
